# How to allow users to point a custom domain to a subdomain of me app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, server

I have an app where when users sign up, their content resides on a subdomain of my app, something like:

user1.example.com

Now I want them to be able to point their custom domain to this subdomain, so that when you visit user1s-domain.com you see the content that was on user1.example.com

The app is a Ruby on Rails app, currently hosted on Heroku. I'm happy to move it to AWS if I can't do what I need on Heroku.

Can you please advise on how this would be accomplished?

Comment: What happens if they simply create a CNAME record in their domain that points to the subdomain in your app?

Comment: When I do that it hits Heroku, but it shows the Heroku page that says 'There's nothing here yet.', so it doesn't know what app it's associated with, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku requires you to configure your account ahead of time with the domain(s) you want to serve. If your app was running on an EC2 server on AWS you could configure your server to accept any domain, at which point the user could point CNAME records to their subdomain.